# Errors destroying and reading sessions in PHP

Tags: php

I have a PHP 7 app that works well on all servers it's installed on except one. All servers are Windows (I believe server 2008 R2 and 2012). The problem is that on one of the servers, we keep getting two kinds of errors sporadically, seemingly randomly. One of the errors is

> session_destroy(): Session object destruction failed

and the other is

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Unknown: open(E:\tmp\sess_6qlo69vbii0qs65i4n47blafi3, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)' in Unknown:0

Every search I do on these errors go back to permissions, which makes sense aside from the fact that it's not happening every time, it's random. What am I missing here, could anything cause the permissions on the file to be different when the session gets created for some reason in certain situations? Or anything else that could possibly explain this behavior?

Comment: Are you running some scripts on the command line (e.g. via a cron) and others via a web server? This could explain different permissions.
Or maybe using a mountable drive that is sometimes not available ?

Comment: There are scripts that run command line, but they don't use sessions, so they would not generate the session files.